# Why IntelliJ multiline TODO comments don't work in .feature files?

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, multiline

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Ultimate Edition). This is what happens when I try to write a multiline comment in a Cucumber `.feature` file. It works fine in `.java` files. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you use line comment in Java or block comments?

Comment: @y.bedrov I have tested this with inline comments `//` and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I reported issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-313788/Multiline-TODO-comments-not-supported. Please follow it for updates.